# How to drop duplicates using conditions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

How can I delete duplicates, while keeping the minimum value of `level` per each duplicated pair of `item_id` and `country_id`.

```
+-----------+----------+---------------+                                        
|item_id    |country_id|level          |
+-----------+----------+---------------+
|     312330|  13535670|             82|
|     312330|  13535670|            369|
|     312330|  13535670|            376|
|     319840|  69731210|            127|
|     319840|  69730600|            526|
|     311480|  69628930|            150|
|     311480|  69628930|            138|
|     311480|  69628930|            405|
+-----------+----------+---------------+
```

The expected output:

```
+-----------+----------+---------------+                                        
|item_id    |country_id|level          |
+-----------+----------+---------------+
|     312330|  13535670|             82|
|     319840|  69731210|            127|
|     319840|  69730600|            526|
|     311480|  69628930|            138|
+-----------+----------+---------------+
```

I know how to delete duplicates without conditions using `dropDuplicates`, but I don't know how to do it for my particular case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the method is to use `orderBy` (default is ascending order), `groupBy` and aggregation `first`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.first
df.orderBy("level").groupBy("item_id", "country_id").agg(first("level").as("level")).show(false)
```

You can define the order as well by using `.asc` for ascending and `.desc` for descending as below

```
df.orderBy($"level".asc).groupBy("item_id", "country_id").agg(first("level").as("level")).show(false)
```

And you can do the operation using `window` and `row_number` function too as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("item_id", "country_id").orderBy($"level".asc)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number
df.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(windowSpec)).filter($"rank" === 1).drop("rank").show()
```

Comment: The first method will take the minimum value of `level`, not the maximum, right?

Comment: first will take the first row of the grouping. If the ordering is ascending then its the minimum and if its descending then the maximum.

Comment: `orderBy($"level".asc)` is marked in red for me. I use Spark 2.2 and Scala 2.11.8

Comment: why would somebody downvote without even commenting. Please comment the drawbacks if you really want to downvote so that I can improve the answer and if the answer is inappropriate then I shall delete it. I just don't understand why people downvote even without commenting.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but are you sure `orderBy` with `first` is guaranteed to work? In my experience it doesn't always do what you might expect in a distributed setup.

Comment: Yes, definitely @Jasper-M It works as Spark api is designed to work in distributed way. groupBy would distribute grouped dataframe to each executor and order them and takes the first from them. And furthermore I have included window function too which is better than groupBy.

Comment: In the meantime I saw that the accepted answer to the question which this one duplicates says exactly the same as me, so I tend to agree with the downvoter that this answer is party incorrect.